# Is the debugger plug-in not available for PostgreSQL 9.2 EnterpriseDB for Win7 x-64

Tags: debugging, plugins, failed-installation, postgresql-9.2, enterprisedb

I followed the installation notes  C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\doc\installation-notes.html

1. Edited the postgresql.conf file  `shared_preload_libraries = '$libdir/plugin_debugger.dll'`
2. Stopped and Restarted the PostgreSQL service in pgAdmin
3. Went into database and ran `CREATE EXTENSION pldbgapi;` which returned with success.

But when I right-click on a function in the TreeView of pgAdmin, there's no debug option and the debugging option is grayed out on the Tools menu.

> pl/pgsql Debugger
>
> The package includes EnterpriseDB's pl/pgsql debugger plugin which may
>   be used by the debugger UI in pgAdmin to help with development of your
>   database functions. The debugger plugin is disabled by default for
>   performance reasons. To enable it, follow the following steps:
>   1.Edit the postgresql.conf file in the data directory and modify the shared_preload_libraries config option to look like the following, if
>   running on Linux or Mac:   shared_preload_libraries =
>   '$libdir/plugin_debugger.so'   or if you are on Windows:
>   shared_preload_libraries = '$libdir/plugin_debugger.dll'
>
> 2.Restart the PostgreSQL server.
>
> 3.Run CREATE EXTENSION pldbgapi; in the database you wish to debug using psql or the pgAdmin query tool.

link: 
https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/debugger.html

Comment: I also done all settings also checked my shared_preload_libraries in server configuration but still its not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One has to go into the Server Configuration on the Tools menu and enable `shared_preload_libraries` item by checking the checkbox next to it. Editing the configuration file and bouncing the database server alone don't enable the debugger in the database.